# HandleError not working in mvc controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I can't get [HandleError] to work in my mvc controller.

I'm guessing it's some kind of configuration issue, but I've tried a lot of things and none of them work.

Things I've tried so far:

web.config custom errors:

```
<customErrors mode="On" />
```

I double-checked that the web.config was the *correct* one (the one located in the root folder)

web.config debug:

```
<compilation debug="true">
```

I tried adding the defaultRedirect to my customErrors:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error" />
```

The error page (Error.cshtml) already works for other specific errors thrown, so there are no exceptions in the Error page itself.

I have read that if the error page uses a master page then that could create an issue.  I'm not using a master page *per se*, but my error page does require a model (ErrorModel), so that might be causing an issue?

Code in question:

```
[HandleError()]
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    [OutputCache(Duration = 0)]
    [Route("bookmarks", Name = HomeControllerRoute.GetBookmarks)]
    public ActionResult Bookmarks()
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

Running the code in Visual Studio presents me with this error:

[Visual Studio error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lD4md.png)

Relevant (as far as I know) info:

- Using MVC 5 + Razor
- IE 11
- Using [MVC Boilerplate](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6cf50a48-fc1e-4eaf-9e82-0b2a6705ca7d)

Comment: How does this work with Chrome?

Comment: Do you still see the exception message in VS if you use `Start without DEBUGGING` (CTRL+F5) rather than `Start Debugging` (F5)?